# Get Google API Client_ID and Client_Secret automatically

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'am currently working on my C# program that sync my Outlook-Calendar-Events to my Google-Calendar. To get connected to my Google calendar I need my Client-ID and my Client-Secret. At the moment I have to write my data manually to my C# code but thats quite annoying. Are there any possibilities to get the Google API Client-ID and the Client-Secret with the first login so I don't have to write them manually to my code?

This is how my current function looks like to get authenticated:

```
public CalendarService authentication()
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                       new ClientSecrets
                                       {
                                           ClientId = MY_CLIENT_ID,
                                           ClientSecret = MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                       },
                                       new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                                       "user",
                                       CancellationToken.None).Result;

        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        return service;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to automatically generate the client ID and secret. Since, this is something that is private to your application. The only way to generate the Google client ID and secret is through the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

However, the only one you can automatically generate is the access token since this is short-lived. To do this, you would need to have the refresh token of the user (assuming the user is authenticated and approves). Hope this helps and Good luck.